# Oracle XE 18C Express Edition Ora-12541 : TNS : No listener

Tags: networking, tns, oracle18c, ora-12541

I installed Oracle XE 18C Express Edition on my Windows 10 and successefully connected to the pluggable database XEPDB1 the first time.After that, all my temptations to connect to this database have failed.
The error I receive is :

```
Ora-12541 : TNS : No listener.
```

Checking the control pannel, all the following services are running:
**OracleOraDB18Home1MTSRecoveryService
OracleOraDB18Home1TNSListener
OracleServiceXE**
only the following service is not:
**OracleVssWriterXE**.
When i checked the default listener "xe" status I got:

```
LSNRCTL> status xe
Connexion α (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=****)(PORT=1521)))
TNS-12541: TNS : aucun processus d'Θcoute
 TNS-12560: TNS : erreur d'adaptateur de protocole
  TNS-00511: Pas de processus d'Θcoute
   64-bit Windows Error: 61: Unknown error
Connexion α (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
TNS-12541: TNS : aucun processus d'Θcoute
 TNS-12560: TNS : erreur d'adaptateur de protocole
  TNS-00511: Pas de processus d'Θcoute
   64-bit Windows Error: 2: No such file or directory
```

Here's the content of my listener.ora:

```
# listener.ora Network Configuration File: C:\app\windows\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\NETWORK\ADMIN\listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = XE

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\app\windows\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:C:\app\windows\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\bin\oraclr18.dll")
    )
  )

XE =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ****)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )
```

And here's my tnsnames.ora:

```
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: C:\app\windows\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\NETWORK\ADMIN\tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ****)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )

LISTENER_XE =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ****)(PORT = 1521))


ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )
```

Comment: Can you post the complete output of "lsnrctl status"? Also check the listener log file to see if there are any more detailed error messages there.

Comment: Sure ! I just edited my post by adding contents of both listener.ora and tnsnames.ora.

Comment: I appear to have this problem now. Did you find an Answer/Solution?

Answer (score 2):

Given the tnsnames.ora file you posted you need to add an entry for the XEPDB1 pluggable database.

copy the existing entry for XE and paste below the XE entry.

Edit the line XE = to read XEPDB1 = and edit the SERVICE_NAME line changing XE to XEPDB1

Save the changes, close the file, stop all the Oracle services, restart all the Oracle services and all should be well.